# Setting wkhtmltopdf path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having this error when I try to use wicked_pdf:

```
irb: No such file or directory - which wkhtmltopdf
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.chomp
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/wicked_pdf-0.7.2/lib/wicked_pdf.r
b:19:in `initialize'
        from (irb):2:in `new'
        from (irb):2
        from :0
```

I think the path to wkhtmltopdf should be configured. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the sources](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/51a211489cc2279992f8bf4373fa31f148df3cb6/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L19), simply add it to your `$PATH` (the folder containing the binary).

Comment: Read the line again. If `defined? Bundler` is false, `which wkhtmltopdf` is called.

Comment: Yep, it worked best for me (wkhtmltopdf being in different places on production, beta, and development) to just not define the exe_path. That way it found it by itself dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

Provide sth like

```
:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf', # path to binary
```

with your render call and make sure, that a wkhtmltopdf binary resides at that path.
(You can get wkhtmltopdf from [google code](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) in case you have not installed it yet)

Comment: Where do i include that piece of code sir? Thanks for your answer anyhow.

Comment: You should have a "render :pdf => '...'" somewhere. Just add ", :wkhtmltopdf => 'path/to/your/binary'" there, maybe introduce a constant so ýou may adjust for live deployment later on.

Answer (score 1):

Wkhtmltopdf project can't be found on Google Code any longer. It was moved to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

In my case, I just had to download the OSX binary and it was automatically added to my PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create an initializer: `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
}
```

`:exe_path` should hold the path to the `wkhtmltopdf` binary. For my instance, I used the gem:

`gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"`

Which stored the binary in my `GEM_HOME`, so I could reference a path that wasnt hard coded.